# log4j2 logger writes to log when used in one class doesn't write when used in another class

Tags: java, logging, log4j2, minecraft, minecraft-forge

Apache log4j2 logger prints to console, not to file when run in one class(Server side). The same logger if placed in other(client side) logs to file as expected.

the `log4j2.xml` is placed in the right folder(i.e src\main\resources) and works for other loggers in the project. I don't understand why logger behaves one way in one class(client side) and other way in another class(server side).

**GameLogger.java**

```
public class GameLogger {

    public static GameLogger INSTANCE = new GameLogger();
    public static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("MyGame");
    @SubscribeEvent
    public synchronized void onPlayerTick(final TickEvent.PlayerTickEvent tick) {
        if (tick.phase == Phase.END) {
            if (tick.player.isEntityAlive()) {  
                        logger.info("Logger is working");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

**log4j2.xml**

```
<RollingRandomAccessFile name="StatsFile" fileName="logs/StatsFile-latest.log" filePattern="logs/StatsFile/%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}{GMT}-%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss}{GMT}%msg%n" />
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
            </Policies>
        </RollingRandomAccessFile>

<Logger level="info" name="MyGame" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="StatsFile" />
        </Logger>
        <Root level="all">
            <AppenderRef ref="FmlSysOut" level="INFO" />
            <AppenderRef ref="ServerGuiConsole" level="INFO" />
            <AppenderRef ref="FmlFile"/>
        </Root>
```

Comment: What do you mean by server side and client side? What are the class names?

Comment: Classes in Minecraft, Client is direct java file which executes every 1/20 of second, Server is another class file which works for any number of clients connected to it.

Comment: Please take the time to provide an [MCVE](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/) per the help article [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just needed to add

```
-Dlog4j.configurationFile=/src/main/resources/log4j2.xml
```

in the vm Arguments.